# Python - Lookup value from one table that falls within a range in a second table

Tags: python, lookup, arcpy

I have two tables, one contains `SCHEDULE_DATE` (over 300,000 records) and `WORK_WEEK_CODE`, and the second table contains `WORK_WEEK_CODE`, `START_DATE`, and `END_DATE`. The first table has duplicate schedule dates, and the second table is 3,200 unique values.  I need to populate the `WORK_WEEK_CODE` in table one with the `WORK_WEEK_CODE` from table two, based off of the range where the schedule date falls.  Samples of the two tables are below.

I was able to accomplish the task using `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` with a nested arcpy.da.SearchCursor, but with the volume of records, it takes a long time.  Any suggestions on a better (and less time consuming) method would be greatly appreciated.

*Note*: The date fields are formatted as string

**Table 1**

```
SCHEDULE_DATE,WORK_WEEK_CODE  
20160219    
20160126    
20160219    
20160118    
20160221    
20160108    
20160129    
20160201    
20160214    
20160127
```

**Table 2**

```
WORK_WEEK_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE  
1601,20160104,20160110  
1602,20160111,20160117  
1603,20160118,20160124  
1604,20160125,20160131  
1605,20160201,20160207  
1606,20160208,20160214  
1607,20160215,20160221
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pandas dataframes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) as a more efficient method. Here is the approach using Pandas. Hope this helps:

```
    import pandas as pd

    # First you need to convert your data to Pandas Dataframe I read them from csv
    Table1 = pd.read_csv('Table1.csv')
    Table2 = pd.read_csv('Table2.csv')

    # Then you need to add a shared key for join
    Table1['key'] = 1
    Table2['key'] = 1

    #The following line joins the two tables
    mergeddf = pd.merge(Table1,Table2,how='left',on='key')

    #The following line converts the string dates to actual dates
    mergeddf['SCHEDULE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(mergeddf['SCHEDULE_DATE'],format='%Y%m%d')
    mergeddf['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(mergeddf['START_DATE'],format='%Y%m%d')
    mergeddf['END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(mergeddf['END_DATE'],format='%Y%m%d')

    #The following line will filter and keep only lines that you need
    result = mergeddf[(mergeddf['SCHEDULE_DATE'] >= mergeddf['START_DATE']) & (mergeddf['SCHEDULE_DATE'] <= mergeddf['END_DATE'])]
```